# Выборка строк mysql по заданному парамерту

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Суть следующая:
Имеется таблица

```
id id_abitur quest answer 
1 20170001 exam 9
2 20170001 exam 10
3 20170001 exam 17
8 20170002 exam 9
9 20170002 exam 10
10 20170002 exam 14
11 20170002 exam 17
16 20170003 exam 9
17 20170003 exam 10
18 20170003 exam 14
19 20170003 exam 17
24 20170004 exam 9
25 20170004 exam 10
```

допустим мне нужна выборка `id_abitur`, у которых `quest`='exam' и `answer` только 9,10,17
делая запрос

```
SELECT `id_abitur`, COUNT(`id`) AS c 
FROM meta_abitur 
WHERE  `quest`='exam' AND `answer` IN (9,10,17) 
GROUP BY `id_abitur` 
HAVING c = 3
```

Выводятся 
id 9,10,17 а так же у которых 9,10,17,19, т.е. те у которых есть еще одна строка.
Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заменим `COUNT` на `SUM`. Если ответил на нужные вопросы - прибавляем один. Если на другие - отнимаем 1. Берем только те, где сумма равна трём:

```
SELECT `id_abitur`, 
sum(case when `answer` IN (9,10,17) then 1 else -1 end) AS c FROM meta_abitur 
WHERE  `quest`='exam'  GROUP BY `id_abitur` HAVING c = 3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef21d2/5

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT `t1`.`id_abitur`
FROM
  tab AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    `t2`.`id_abitur`
  FROM
    tab AS `t2`
  WHERE
    `t2`.`answer` NOT IN (9,10,17) AND
    `t2`.`quest` = 'exam'
) AS `j` ON
  `t1`.`id_abitur` = `j`.`id_abitur`
WHERE
  `j`.`id_abitur` IS NULL AND
  `t1`.`quest` = 'exam'
GROUP BY
  `t1`.`id_abitur`
HAVING
  COUNT(`t1`.`id_abitur`) = 3
```

На [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd34ba/38/0).

Answer (score 0):

Группируй по полю answer:

```
SELECT 
  id_abitur, 
  COUNT(id) AS c 
FROM 
  meta_abitur 
WHERE  
  quest='exam' AND 
  answer IN (9,10,17) 
GROUP BY 
  answer 
HAVING c = 3
```

Comment: И что мы тут получим? Группировка по `answer` даст нам ответы, на которые ответили три студента.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант: Внутренний подзапрос определяет количество ответов для каждого абитуриента. Внешний запрос соединяет таблицу meta_abitur с подзапросом с учетом количества `(c)` и номеров `(answer in (9,10,17))` правильных ответов и параметра `quest`

`select distinct id_abitur from meta_abitur i inner join (select id_abitur,count(*) as c from meta_abitur WHERE quest='exam' group by 1
having c=3) o USING(id_abitur) where answer in (9,10,17);`

Comment: Не отфильтрует студентов, которые дали и другие `answer` - эти ответы просто не попадут в выборку и не будут обрабатываться в `HAVING`.

Comment: @Zifur Из вопроса автора "допустим мне нужна выборка id_abitur, у которых quest='exam' и answer только 9,10,17 " другие answer не   нужны

Comment: Так там же дальше: "Выводятся id 9,10,17 а так же у которых 9,10,17,19, т.е. те у которых есть еще одна строка. Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?". С Вашим запросом будет то же самое.

Comment: Вот результат запроса:  
20170001  3  20170002  3  20170003  3

Comment: А должна быть одна строка - 20170001. Только этот ID дал ТОЛЬКО указанные три ответа.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135617)

Comment: @ilyaplot Скрипт работает и выдает то, что нужно автору, я проверил перед постом, Что не так с ответом ?

Comment: Прокомментируйте свой sql запрос и оформите нормально ответ.